# Hide input field and show output field on button click

Tags: visualforce

I have a scenario in which I have created a vf page. My vf page contains both input and output field, and also there is "review" button at the bottom. I want to perform a task in which some one click on the "review" button the input fields gets hidden and the output field appears. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Post your code for better information.

Answer (score 0):

On click of button you can have javascript/jQuery defined which will show or hide the tags or div based on Id.
Below is the sample code which behaves the same way

```
<apex:page>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <apex:slds />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#clicked').click(function() {
                $('#divId').toggle();
            });
      });
    </script>

    <div id="divId">
        <apex:outputText value="This is outputtext" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="clicked">Click Me!</button>    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rendered` attribute to toggle between `inputField` and `outputField` i.e. use a boolean field which can be toggled on click of `Review` button and based on this boolean field you can render or not render the input and output fields.

Pseudo code of the visualforce

```
<apex:pageblocksection id="section">
    <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}" rendered="{!NOT(showOutput)}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Name}" rendered="{!showOutput}" />
</apex:pageblocksection>
<apex:commandButton value="Review" action="{!reviewInputs}" rerender="section"/>
```

On click of Review button set `showOutput` to `true` and `rerender` the entire section which will hide the input fields and show the output fields.

Comment: Hi @user77686  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.